# Jquery to compare rows in two tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have to compare values in the cells of two tables using jquery.
Usin the values of the table one  i should compare firstname, middlename and last name with table 2. If these 3 values match with table 2 row then i should color the row in second table.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamsrk/fojz5e56/10/)**

```
<table id="T1" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Suffix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>78</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="T2" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Suffix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bat</td>
      <td>man</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>21212</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>james</td>
      <td>bond</td>
      <td>007</td>
      <td>dadadada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>78</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

<button id="btn">color if matches</button>
```

Comment: Can you share your JS code as well. I do not see it in question or fiddle. SO is not get code for free site.

Comment: Can you please check it now. I was able to write it for rows.. But i have to take the values of only firstname last name and middlename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function(e){
        $('#T1 tbody tr').each(function(){
        var row = $(this);
        var left_cols = $(this).find("td:lt(3)");
        $('#T2 tbody tr').each(function(){
            var right_cols = $(this).find("td:lt(3)");
            if(left_cols.html() == right_cols.html()) {
                left_cols.css('background-color', 'green').css('color', 'red');
                right_cols.css('background-color', 'green').css('color', 'red');
             }
         });
      });
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you have a look at the fiddle...its not two rows but first three coloumns of the row

Comment: Your code works fine if the whole row matches...i was able to write the same in the fiddler but i want to take only three columns in the row and match with three columns in each row for rest in the second table

Comment: Oh, okay. I seem to have misunderstood it. Please give me a moment. :)

Comment: thanks that works. Is there a way i can take one value at a time from column.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you gotta run another loop for the td's in that case. But that's hardly necessary in this case.

Comment: I have a bigger table to match so just checking this condition if i can take it each value and compare it

Comment: How to find the specific cell?           var left_cols = $(this).children().eq(1);
                                                          var right_cols = $(this).children().eq(2);  this does not work.